# Firestore returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function here in a separate file, where:

```
export const getListOfChannels = (id) => {
  const channels = []

  firestore.collection("channels").where("channelId", "==", id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      channels.push(doc.data().id)
    })
  })
  return channels
}
```

And in another file, I'm doing:

```
// This is returning an empty array
const returnFromFirebase = getListOfChannelsIdWithCommunityId(id)
```

It wasn't supposed to return an empty array, because if I do a `console.log(doc.data().id)` I can see the data.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase APIs (and any API that returns a promise) are asynchronous and return immediately, before the query is complete.  The callback you provide via `then` is invoked some time later, after the results are available.  There is no guarantee how quickly this will happen.  As such, it's not possible to make a function that returns the query results immediately.

For asynchronous calls, what you're supposed to do is make your wrapper function also return a promise, and make the caller use that promise to get the results:

```
export const getListOfChannels = (id) => {
  return firestore.collection("channels").where("channelId", "==", id).get();
}

getListOfChannelsIdWithCommunityId(id).then(querySnapshot => {
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    channels.push(doc.data().id)
  })
})
```

There are a lot of variations on how to do this, but there is no alternative to dealing with that promise asynchronously.  I strongly suggest learning how promises work, as it is critical to writing effective JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

`getListOfChannels` is having code that does async call and you are returning `channels` outside of `then` and therefore it will always be empty.

**So, return the promise**

```js
export const getListOfChannels = (id) => {
  const channels = []

  return firestore.collection("channels").where("channelId", "==", id).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      channels.push(doc.data().id)
    })
    return channels;
  })
}
```

**And in Another file access it in `then` block**

```js
let returnFromFirebase = [];
getListOfChannelsIdWithCommunityId(id).then((res) => {
  returnFromFirebase = res;
});
```